# .htaccess rewrite complex url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have this url:

> http://www.mysite.com/pronostici/data/2012/aprile-2012/7216-prono-02-04-2012

I have redirect to

> http://www.mysite.com/pronostici/data_incontri/2012-04-02

How would I go about doing this in .htaccess?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to redirect **just** that URL, or a lot of similar ones?

Comment: exactly: http://www.mysite.com/pronostici/data/year/month-year/number-pronostico-day-month-year
in: http://www.mysite.com/pronostici/data_incontri/year-month-day
where:
year=2012 or 2011
month=all months
number=from 1000 to 17000
day=01..31
month=01..12
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your source URL, you can use the date at the end to build your target URL. So, something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule pronostici/data/.*/\d+-prono-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$ http://www.mysite.com/pronostici/data_incontri/$3-$2-$1 [R=301,L]
```